GeoListPlot markers according to label
Given the following data as a table with two columns (a GeoPosition and a string motion label), how do I GeoListPlot this such that the point is colored according to the value of motion (which can be 'stationary', 'driving', some other value, or even Missing[NotAvailable])?
GeoListPlot will plot the points, but then legend gives a different color for each point with an insanely huge legend when points with 'stationary' should be one color, 'driving' should be another color, &c.
data = {{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6822}],stationary},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6822}],stationary},  
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6822}],Missing[NotAvailable]},  
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6822}],stationary},  
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6822}],stationary},   
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],stationary},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],stationary},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],stationary},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],stationary},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],Missing[NotAvailable]},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],Missing[NotAvailable]},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],Missing[NotAvailable]},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],stationary},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],Missing[NotAvailable]},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],stationary},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],stationary},
{GeoPosition[{28.3562,-81.6823}],stationary}
}


It seems that GeoListPlot has some troubles dealing with labels. I only managed to do it by explicitly providing PlotLegends.
(* Generate random points, because your points are all the same ... *)
data = Table[{RandomGeoPosition[], 
        RandomChoice[{"stationary", "driving", Missing["NotAvailable"]}]}, 30];

groupedData = KeySort[GroupBy[data, Last]];
GeoListPlot[Values@groupedData, PlotMarkers -> Point, 
 PlotLegends -> Keys@groupedData]



Worked like a charm; thank you @Domen
